# Android update ListFragment's listView from another fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-listview

I have a question about updating my ListView in ListFragment from my Map fragment. Each time I will call this method I will assign different values to String Array. And what should I put into that Update method to refresh the listview ?

Comment: use BroadcastReceiver

Comment: Can you please post a snippet or something ?

Answer (score 0):

In ListFragment create and register `BroadcastReceiver` :

```
static final String ACTION_CUSTOM = "action";
BroadcastReceiver mReceiver;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   mReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver(){
        public void onReceive(android.content.Context context, Intent intent) {

            //Check for action you need
            if (intent.getAction() == ACTION_CUSTOM ){
                //Do stuff with data from intent
                intent.getExtras().getString("data");
             }
        }
    };
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    getActivity().registerReceiver(receiver, new IntentFilter(ACTION_CUSTOM ));
}


@Override
protected void onPause() {
     super.onPause();
     getActivity().unregisterReceiver(receiver);
}
```

In MapFragment send broadcast intent, when you need to change data:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();

//Set action you need to send
intent.setAction(ACTION_CUSTOM);

//Add data to send
intent.putExtra("data", "data_value");

//Send broadcast intent
getActivity().sendBroadcast(intent);
```

Comment: Hmm. Thanks but it didn't answer my question. I wanted to know how to do that part //do stuff with your data e.g. How to refredh listFragment